# pymongo to work with multiple db - readreplica set , main mongodb server

Tags: mongodb, pymongo

using pymongo can we direct the read operation to readreplica set and write operation to main mongodb server.

For e.g. When I do db.mycollection.find It should access Readreplica MongoDB and when we do db.mycollection.update or db.mycollection.remove It should access main MongoDB to do the operation.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the [documentation](http://api.mongodb.org/python/current/examples/high_availability.html), you can set the read preference at client, database or collection level, see below. You will have to create two instances of a collection (or database or client), one for writing to the primary and a second one for reading from the secondary.

```
from pymongo import MongoClient
from pymongo import ReadPreference

client = MongoClient('localhost:27017', readPreference='secondaryPreferred')
client.read_preference
db = client.get_database('test', read_preference=ReadPreference.SECONDARY)
db.read_preference
coll = db.get_collection('test', read_preference=ReadPreference.PRIMARY)
coll.read_preference
```

Comment: actually I am looking for something like this, client = MongoClient(read_from="IP_OF_READ_REPLICA", write_to="IP_OF_MAIN_MONGO_SERVER")

Comment: That doesn't exist, you will have to wrap `MongoClient` in a custom clas to achieve this.